# When would isSearchable return false for an Oracle JDBC column?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

In what cases would a call to `java.sql.ResultSetMetaData.isSearchable(int col)` return false for an Oracle database? The [documentation](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#isSearchable(int)) for the method doesn't really answer the question:

> ```
> "Indicates whether the designated column can be used in a where clause."
> ```

I can think of only one case - when the column is the result of an aggregate function (in which case it would have to be part of a `HAVING` filter, not a `WHERE` filter).

Are there any other cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more related to the type of the column value, not how the column is selected. This information is stored in [`DatabaseMetaData#getTypeInfo()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getTypeInfo%28%29). The column `SEARCHABLE` can return either [`DatabaseMetaData.typePredNone`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#typePredNone) (not searchable) or other values.

> 9: **SEARCHABLE** short => can you use `"WHERE"` based on this type:
>
> - `typePredNone` - No support
> - `typePredChar` - Only supported with `WHERE .. LIKE`
> - `typePredBasic` - Supported except for `WHERE .. LIKE`
> - `typeSearchable` - Supported for all `WHERE ..`

Here's a snippet which displays this information:

```
DatabaseMetaData databaseMetaData = connection.getMetaData();
ResultSet typeInfo = databaseMetaData.getTypeInfo();
System.out.println("type name                      | data type | searchable");
System.out.println("-------------------------------+-----------+------------");
while (typeInfo.next()) {
    String typeName = typeInfo.getString("TYPE_NAME");
    int dataType = typeInfo.getInt("DATA_TYPE");
    boolean searchable = typeInfo.getShort("SEARCHABLE") != DatabaseMetaData.typePredNone;
    System.out.printf("%-30s | %-9d | %-9s%n", typeName , dataType, searchable);
}
```

This yields something like following on a PostgreSQL 8.4 connection:

```
type name                      | data type | searchable
-------------------------------+-----------+------------
bool                           | -7        | true     
bytea                          | -2        | true     
char                           | 1         | true     
name                           | 12        | true     
int8                           | -5        | true     
bigserial                      | -5        | true     
int2                           | 5         | true     
int2vector                     | 1111      | true     
int4                           | 4         | true     
serial                         | 4         | true     
regproc                        | 1111      | true     
text                           | 12        | true     
(*snip*, it were about 270 rows, all TRUE by the way)
```

The `data type` is correlatable with [`ResultSetMetaData#getColumnType()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnType%28int%29).

Comment: So there are no examples where this would be false? What's the point then? :)

Comment: I honestly have no idea. I've never used it as well, I don't see any real world benefits for this, except maybe in webbased database management tools on top of JDBC. I by the way did another test on MySQL, also all true. I also did a more explicit test on `typeInfo.getShort("SEARCHABLE") == DatabaseMetaData.typeSearchable` and it was all `true`.

Comment: @BalusC Thanks for the answer, any idea how to determine which columns  from the original query were aggregate functions?

Answer (score 0):

@BalusC [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952061/when-would-issearchable-return-false-for-an-oracle-jdbc-column/2974214#2974214) isn't update to date, when executed on Oracle 12, there are several *searchable=false* types (as LONG):

```
type name                      | data type | searchable
-------------------------------+-----------+------------
INTERVALDS                     | -104      | true     
INTERVALYM                     | -103      | true     
TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE | -102      | true     
TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE       | -101      | true     
NCHAR                          | -15       | true     
NVARCHAR2                      | -9        | true     
NUMBER                         | -7        | true     
NUMBER                         | -6        | true     
NUMBER                         | -5        | true     
LONG RAW                       | -4        | false    
RAW                            | -3        | true     
LONG                           | -1        | false    
CHAR                           | 1         | true     
NUMBER                         | 2         | true     
NUMBER                         | 4         | true     
NUMBER                         | 5         | true     
FLOAT                          | 6         | true     
REAL                           | 7         | true     
VARCHAR2                       | 12        | true     
DATE                           | 92        | true     
DATE                           | 93        | true     
TIMESTAMP                      | 93        | true     
STRUCT                         | 2002      | false    
ARRAY                          | 2003      | false    
BLOB                           | 2004      | false    
CLOB                           | 2005      | false    
REF                            | 2006      | false    
NCLOB                          | 2011      | false
```